# Can I use just "no one/nobody" meaning "no one was there"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it possible to shorten the phrase, when the context is clear about the place?

*He opened the door. Nobody was there.* -> *He opened the door. Nobody.*

Or is there a better short term in English? Is *nothing* an option since we suppose the absence of  a person, but there are literally empty space?

P.S. I searched Google books and context translators for this, but they don't show the results I need. Search in dictionaries suppose that *no one* and *nobody* are the best options.

Comment: You can write in any style you like. This is not something you can look up. At all. :)

Comment: Some people will say "Nobody." is not a complete sentence because it has no verb. Other people will say that sort of thing is fine, and it is common, especially in fiction. If you're writing for a teacher/professor/editor, find out what they think. Else, you can do what you like.

Comment: _There was nobody there_ might be the most conventional way to say it, but if it's narrative written in the style that quotes the protagonist's thoughts, _Nobody_ is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the narrative has made clear that the protagonist is checking for someone, then it sounds OK to shorten it to "Nobody" or "No one". Or an idiom to add emphasis: "Not a soul", "Nobody/not a person in sight".